# updateOne $set function won't work in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update the subdocument `books` within the array without success. The new data won't get saved.

Express:

```
router.put("/:id/:bookid", (req, res) => {
  Library.updateOne(
    { _id: req.params.id, "books._id": req.params.bookid },
    { $set: { "books.$.title": "New value" } }
  );
});
```

LibraryScema:

```
const LibarySchema = new Library({
  Name: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  }, 
  books: [BookSchema]
});
```

bookScema:

```
const BookSchema = new Schema({

  title: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  Chapters: [
    {
      chapterTitle: {
        type: String,
        required: false
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Libary Table:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "12345"
    },
    "Name": "A random libary",
    "Books": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "1"
        }
        "title": "TitleExample",
        "Chapters": [{
            chapterTitle: "first chapter etc"
        }]             
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "2"
        }
        "title": "Another book"  ,
        "Chapters": [{
            chapterTitle: "first chapter etc"
        }]  
    }]
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the document you're trying to update and the values of `req.params.id` and `req.params.bookid`?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877967/mongoose-doesnt-update-my-document-if-i-have-no-callback-function

Comment: @JohnnyHK Updated answer with the document, check "edit"

Comment: You're not actually executing the update; see the linked dupe.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Should adding `.exec();` be enough? Still having issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
router.put("/:id/:bookid", (req, res) => {
    Library.findOne({ _id: req.params.id, "books._id": req.params.bookid }).exec(function(err,result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result) {
            result.books.title = "new value";
            result.save()
            console.log("new value")
        } else {
            console.log("not found")
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: There is no error when I check the terminal. Or do I have to add something to check if there's an error?

Comment: Didn't work, I think the problem is that the title are still array. I checked `console.log(result.books);`, and title is in array after `result.books`, which make the target unreachable? When I used `result.books.title`, I got `undefined`error. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: what is $oid i cant see in your schema

Comment: I could change the books title by:   `result.books =  [{ title: 'new value' }];`, but everything else within that array gets deleted. Is that suppose to do that or did I do it wrong?

Comment: The `$oid` is auto-generated by mongoose when a new row is created. I just need to use `_id` to compare the value with it.

Comment: books._id not equal library _id so you get undefined error