# Push a value to array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i'm trying to push on array a value but not work, i've searched and i've tried many different solutions ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49741871/push-element-to-array-in-mongoose)) or [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621970/pushing-object-into-array-schema-in-mongoose) but nobody works always return:

```
POST /users/addfollower 500 2.353 ms - 1410
```

My code:

```
console.log("Id da aggiungere ai follower: " + req.body.idf);
console.log("Id utente:" + req.user._id);
auth.findAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, {$push: {'amici': {"user": req.body.idf}}}).exec(function(err,res){
//
});
```

My schema:

```
const authschema = mongoose.Schema({
 _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
 username: String,
 nome: String,
 cognome: String,
 email: String,
 password: String,
 cookie: String,
 pp: String,
 descrizione: String,
 autenticazione: Boolean,
 token: String,
 amici: [{
  user: String
 }]
});
```

Creation user:

```
  const auth = new Auth({
    _id : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    username: req.body.username,
    nome: req.body.nome,
    cognome: req.body.cognome,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: hash,
    pp: "/uploads/user.png",
    descrizione: "Aggiungi qui la tua descrizione",
    autenticazione: false,
    token: token,
    amici: [{
      user: "start"
    }]
  });
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: nope, i've tried the two solutions posted but i've the same error....i think that the problem is in the creation user at the array definition but i don't know the problem

Comment: finally i've found the problem, i've write auth not with the uppercase... because when a mongoose method is called i need to refer it to the schema so my schema is Auth not auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've found the problem, i've write auth not with the uppercase... because when a mongoose method is called i need to refer it to the schema so my schema is Auth not auth thanks all :D

```
Auth.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, {$push: {"amici": req.body.idf }}, {safe: true,   upsert: true}, function(err,doc){
if(err){
  console.log(err);
}else{
  console.log("Working \^0^/");
}
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to push an object to `amici` attribute, but you defined it as Array type.

Try changing

```
auth.findAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, {$push: {'amici': {"user": req.body.idf}}}).exec(function(err,res){
//
});
```

to

```
auth.findAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, {$push: {'amici': [{"user": req.body.idf}]}}).exec(function(err,res){
//
});
```

I can't guarantee that's the only problem, but that's a start.

Comment: There is a problem with you schema definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing your schema to:

```
const amiciSchena = mongoose.Schema({
   name: String 
});  

const authschema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    username: String,
    nome: String,
    cognome: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    cookie: String,
    pp: String,
    descrizione: String,
    autenticazione: Boolean,
    token: String,
    amici: [amiciSchena]
});
```