# Array.push does not seem to work on MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I would like to create a dynamic vector/array in MongoDB. The idea is simple: whenever someone submits something, it should update a user in my database in MongoDB. I have created a variable for that. I have already tested: the proper user is found correctly.

Please, find it a snippet of my code.

```
User.findOne({ name })
          .then(user => {                
            user.something.push(something to push);
          })
```

I have set the default value when it is created as empty:

```
  something: {   
    type: [String],
    default: []
  }
```

However, it does not save, and throw no error. 
Anyone has a guess of what might be happening behind the scenes? I am new to MongoDB.

Comment: You have to update it with the method. Here is a post that has examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49741871/push-element-to-array-in-mongoose

Comment: The solution I have found was quite simple: just add user.save() after .push! just one line! It seems that mongoose or mongo, does not salve automatically. Thanks you all for the insights! I went for walk and remembered that I have faced the same problem before! 

Answer (score 5):

You can use findOneAndUpdate() with $push mongodb operator

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({name:name},{$push:{ something: 'new_data'}});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the database with another call.

```
User.findOne({ name })
    .then(user => {                
        user.something.push(something to push);
        User.update({{ _id: user._id }})
    })
```

Or you can directly use

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ name }, { something: ['new_data']});
```